# Visual Studio shows VSS check-out symbol always

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, visual-sourcesafe-2005

This is annoying :(

I see Visual Source Safe check-out symbol besides my files and project even I did check-in to the server. For projects, if I press refresh, it will go away. But while loading the solution next time, the problem comes again. Any workarounds to fix the issue ?

Comment: How do you open the solution in Visual Studio? Did you try opening the solution from source control directly?

Comment: No. From my local disk, I open the solution, then will provide user name and password.

Comment: try opening the solution from VSS directly.